# How can I open a form submission in a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to make a dropdown menu with HTML form/option. When the user clicks on the option desired, it should open a new tab in the same window. I’m currently using a pre-made plugin (made some alterations to the design of my project and adapted to the rest of the code), and managed to make it almost work. The thing is that it doesn’t open in a new tab: it opens on the same page (like _self).

Below, is the HTML code I’m using, as well the javascript file.

I’m really struggling to find a solution, though I know that it might be an easy one. I tried several things but none of them worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!-- begin meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Ex. 1</title>
<!-- end meta -->

<!-- begin CSS -->
<link href="css/style_dropdown.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- end CSS -->    

<!-- begin JS -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
<script>
        $( function() {
            $( '#cd-dropdown' ).dropdown( {
                gutter : 5,
                stack : true,
                slidingIn : 100,
                onOptionSelect : function( opt ) {
                window.location = opt.data( 'value' );  
                }
            } );
        });


<!-- end JS -->
<head>
<body>


            <form>
            <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">

                <option value="-1" selected>Social</option>
                <option value="https://www.facebook.com" class="icon-facebook">Facebook</option>
                <option value="https://plus.google.com/" class="icon-googleplus">Google Plus</option>
                <option value="https://soundcloud.com/" class="icon-soundcloud">Soundcloud</option>
                <option value="https://www.tumblr.com/" class="icon-tumblr">Tumblr</option>
                <option value="http://www.youtube.com/" class="icon-youtube">You Tube</option>

            </select>
            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And now the .js file

```
   /**
 JS DROPDOWN MENU
  */


;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

'use strict';

$.DropDown = function( options, element ) {
    this.$el = $( element );
    this._init( options );
};

// the options
$.DropDown.defaults = {
    speed : 300,
    easing : 'ease',
    gutter : 0,
    // initial stack effect
    stack : true,
    // delay between each option animation
    delay : 0,
    // random angle and positions for the options
    random : false,
    // rotated [right||left||false] : the options will be rotated to thr right side or left side.
    // make sure to tune the transform origin in the stylesheet
    rotated : false,
    // effect to slide in the options. value is the margin to start with
    slidingIn : false,
    onOptionSelect : function(opt) { return false; }
};

$.DropDown.prototype = {

    _init : function( options ) {

        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.DropDown.defaults, options );
        this._layout();
        this._initEvents();

    },
    _layout : function() {

        var self = this;
        this.minZIndex = 1000;
        var value = this._transformSelect();
        this.opts = this.listopts.children( 'li' );
        this.optsCount = this.opts.length;
        this.size = { width : this.dd.width(), height : this.dd.height() };

        var elName = this.$el.attr( 'name' ), elId = this.$el.attr( 'id' ),
            inputName = elName !== undefined ? elName : elId !== undefined ? elId : 'cd-dropdown-' + ( new Date() ).getTime();

        this.inputEl = $( '<input type="hidden" name="' + inputName + '" value="' + value + '"></input>' ).insertAfter( this.selectlabel );

        this.selectlabel.css( 'z-index', this.minZIndex + this.optsCount );
        this._positionOpts();
        if( Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
            setTimeout( function() { self.opts.css( 'transition', 'all ' + self.options.speed + 'ms ' + self.options.easing ); }, 25 );
        }

    },
    _transformSelect : function() {

        var optshtml = '', selectlabel = '', value = -1;
        this.$el.children( 'option' ).each( function() {

            var $this = $( this ),
                val = isNaN( $this.attr( 'value' ) ) ? $this.attr( 'value' ) : Number( $this.attr( 'value' ) ) ,
                classes = $this.attr( 'class' ),
                selected = $this.attr( 'selected' ),
                label = $this.text();

            if( val !== -1 ) {
                optshtml += 
                    classes !== undefined ? 
                        '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></li>' :
                        '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span>' + label + '</span></li>';
            }

            if( selected ) {
                selectlabel = label;
                value = val;
            }

        } );

        this.listopts = $( '<ul/>' ).append( optshtml );
        this.selectlabel = $( '<span/>' ).append( selectlabel );
        this.dd = $( '<div class="cd-dropdown"/>' ).append( this.selectlabel, this.listopts ).insertAfter( this.$el );
        this.$el.remove();

        return value;

    },
    _positionOpts : function( anim ) {

        var self = this;

        this.listopts.css( 'height', 'auto' );
        this.opts
            .each( function( i ) {
                $( this ).css( {
                    zIndex : self.minZIndex + self.optsCount - 1 - i,
                    top : self.options.slidingIn ? ( i + 1 ) * ( self.size.height + self.options.gutter ) : 0,
                    left : 0,
                    marginLeft : self.options.slidingIn ? i % 2 === 0 ? self.options.slidingIn : - self.options.slidingIn : 0,
                    opacity : self.options.slidingIn ? 0 : 1,
                    transform : 'none'
                } );
            } );

        if( !this.options.slidingIn ) {
            this.opts
                .eq( this.optsCount - 1 )
                .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 9 : 0, left : this.options.stack ? 4 : 0, width : this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 8 : this.size.width, transform : 'none' } )
                .end()
                .eq( this.optsCount - 2 )
                .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 6 : 0, left : this.options.stack ? 2 : 0, width : this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 4 : this.size.width, transform : 'none' } )
                .end()
                .eq( this.optsCount - 3 )
                .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 3 : 0, left : 0, transform : 'none' } );
        }

    },
    _initEvents : function() {

        var self = this;

        this.selectlabel.on( 'mousedown.dropdown', function( event ) {
            self.opened ? self.close() : self.open();
            return false;

        } );

        this.opts.on( 'click.dropdown', function() {
            if( self.opened ) {
                var opt = $( this );
                self.options.onOptionSelect( opt );
                self.inputEl.val( opt.data( 'value' ) );
                self.selectlabel.html( opt.html() );
                self.close();

            }
        } );

    },

    open : function() {
        var self = this;
        this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
        this.listopts.css( 'height', ( this.optsCount + 1 ) * ( this.size.height + this.options.gutter ) );
        this.opts.each( function( i ) {

            $( this ).css( {
                opacity : 1,
                top : self.options.rotated ? self.size.height + self.options.gutter : ( i + 1 ) * ( self.size.height + self.options.gutter ),
                left : self.options.random ? Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) : 0,
                width : self.size.width,
                marginLeft : 0,
                transform : self.options.random ?
                    'rotate(' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) + 'deg)' :
                    self.options.rotated ?
                        self.options.rotated === 'right' ?
                            'rotate(-' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)' :
                            'rotate(' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)'
                        : 'none',
                transitionDelay : self.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ? self.options.slidingIn ? ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : 0
            } );

        } );
        this.opened = true;

    },
    close : function() {

        var self = this;
        this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
        if( this.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
            this.opts.each( function( i ) {
                $( this ).css( { 'transition-delay' : self.options.slidingIn ? ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' } );
            } );
        }
        this._positionOpts( true );
        this.opened = false;

    }



}

$.fn.dropdown = function( options ) {
    var instance = $.data( this, 'dropdown' );
    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
        this.each(function() {
            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
        });
    }
    else {
        this.each(function() {
            instance ? instance._init() : instance = $.data( this, 'dropdown', new $.DropDown( options, this ) );
        });
    }
    return instance;
};



} )( jQuery, window );
```

Comment: I couldn't find where you are opening the window?

Answer (score 0):

### Some initial problems

First, you cannot control whether it opens in a new window or in a new tab in the current window: that’s purely a browser setting. If you set the target to `_blank`, it’ll open in a new whatever (probably tab, as that’s the default behaviour of most modern browsers).

Second, your HTML is seriously broken, because the `<head>` contains a `<script>` tag which opens but does not close. (Also, the closing `<head>` tag is written as a second opening tag instead.)

Third, your example is not self-contained, because it is completely unworkable without the accompanying CSS.

### An attempt at an answer

I can’t work out where you’re actually opening anything, in a new window or otherwise. Your form doesn’t have a submit button or anything similarly obviously useful. However, something as simple as adding `target="_blank"` to the opening `<form>` tag might well do the trick.

```
<form target="_blank">
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Social</option>
    <option value="https://www.facebook.com" class="icon-facebook">Facebook</option>
    <option value="https://plus.google.com/" class="icon-googleplus">Google Plus</option>
    <option value="https://soundcloud.com/" class="icon-soundcloud">Soundcloud</option>
    <option value="https://www.tumblr.com/" class="icon-tumblr">Tumblr</option>
    <option value="http://www.youtube.com/" class="icon-youtube">You Tube</option>
</select>
</form>
```